# Como esconder/mostrar elementos do meu HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<ul>
    <li onclick="mostrar('img')">
        PASTA - Fotos
        <ul>
            <li id="img" style="display: none;">Imagem1.jpg</li>
            <li id="img2" style="display: block;"> Imagem2.jpg </li>
        </ul>
    </li><br>
    <li> PASTA - BOLETOS
        <ul>
            <li id="boleto">boleto.pdf</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
function mostrar(){
    let show = document.getElementById('img')
    if(show.style.display == 'none'){
        show.style.display = 'block'
    }
    else{
        show.style.display = 'none'
    }
}

</script>
```

Estou estudando e resolvi testar a lógica de uma Pasta comum de um computador.

1º Clica sobre a pasta e expande(mostra) seus arquivos.

Meu dúvida é: Como fazer isso para a "Imagem2.jpg" sem precisar criar outra função? Quero manter a mesma função.

Obs: Quero a ajuda em Javascript puro, não citem JQuery, pois ainda não estou estudando isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em HTML só podes ter 1 ID única por página, ou seja vários elementos com a mesma ID é HTML inválido. Para selecionar vários elementos podes usar classes. Também é possivel ter um seletor que verifica se uma ID começa com uma dada string... mas classes é mais correto.

**Porém** no teu caso creio que não precisas de classes ou ids, podes usar o elemento que chama `mostrar` como referência se lhe passares o `this`. Assim, sabes que elemento foi clicado e podes procurar `li`s dentro dele. Vais ter de iterar, mas o código seria semelhante.
Nesse caso poderias fazer assim:

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="mostrar(this)">
    PASTA - Fotos
    <ul>
      <li>Imagem1.jpg</li>
      <li>Imagem2.jpg </li>
    </ul>
  </li><br>
  <li> PASTA - BOLETOS
    <ul>
      <li id="boleto">boleto.pdf</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<script>
  function mostrar(el) {
    const lis = el.querySelectorAll('li');
    lis.forEach(li => {
      li.style.display = li.style.display === 'none' ? 'initial' :
        'none';
    });
  }
</script>
```

E outro melhoramento seria, em vez de esconder com JavaScript podes fazer isso com uma classe de CSS.

```css
.esconder li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="mostrar(this)">
    PASTA - Fotos
    <ul>
      <li>Imagem1.jpg</li>
      <li>Imagem2.jpg </li>
    </ul>
  </li><br>
  <li> PASTA - BOLETOS
    <ul>
      <li>boleto.pdf</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<script>
  function mostrar(el) {
    el.classList.toggle('esconder');
  }
</script>
```